# Problem with saving files to S3 and Saving Entry to DB

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-s3, error-handling, transactions

I have a job application form, I takes some inputs:

- FirstName
- LastName
- Phone (Unique Index)
- Email (Unique Index)
- Resume
- ProfilePhoto

I want to save Resume and ProfilePhoto to AWS S3 (as they are files), the problem is if I try to save these 2 files:

- what happens if one file gave some error, it will then have extra space occupied which is problematic.
- what if after saving both files the saving in the DB fails then also the same problem
- if I try to save the entry into DB then what if the files are failed to save.

I face these kind of issues a lot

I tried saving the files first and then save the entry to the DB but the issue still remains

Comment: These are common issues in software development. This is usually solved using transactions; you can "roll back" any changes if the transaction doesn't complete each step successfully. I suggest looking into transaction options for S3 and how to implement this in Node.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @James There is no support for transaction in S3, plus let's say I want to go with the first solution of rolling back the changes, what should I do if rolling back fails?